# OLAP Data Warehouse - composite primary key as multiple or single fields

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse, olap, composite-primary-key

I'm building a data warehouse, and the data is of a quality where 8 fields may be required to uniquely identify a record, and this applies to three tables, each of which will have a few million rows of data per year. It's all 0NF.

Obviously every situation is unique, but considering that the purpose of the data warehouse is for OLAP, am I right in thinking that I would be better to create a single column to use as the primary key rather than a composite primary key of 8 separate fields? It's straightforward to concatenate the fields into an extra column as part of the ETL pipeline.

I appreciate the redundancy increases the storage requirement, and we are talking millions of rows a year, but I'm guessing it'll significantly improve query performance? And reduce memory requirements if the data is modelled in a BI tool?

Can anybody give me any general thoughts or advice on this please?

Below is some entirely made-up simulated data. I need to like the order table to the shipment table to get where the order was shipped from, for example, or maybe the order table to the shipment table to sum the quantity shipped.

I don't think normalising the tables is the way to go, as all four of the columns I'm using here would be subject to change, and only combined they form a reliable key for a unique shipment.

Because of this the data is bulk deleted/inserted based on shift date.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Thanks!

Phil.

Comment: In datawarehouses usually a surrogate key is created

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your response. I'm not sure how I would do this though, as the tables aren't normalised and it's only when I have concatenated a number of columns that I get a reliable unique key.

Comment: What methodology are you using to design your DW - Kimball, Inmon, Data Vault?

Answer (score 0):

Those look like fact tables.  In a dimensional model only dimension tables need single-column keys.  Fact tables typically have compound keys made up of the dimension foreign keys that define the fact table grain.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for responding. Yes, they are fact tables and they do contain dimension foreign keys. But in terms of query performance, would it be better to relate these two fact tables together by creating the shipment_key during ETL as per the example (so the key is a single column), or would it be better to create a compound key for each table rather than create a new column with redundant data?

Comment: If every shipment references an order, I’d put a synthetic key on order.